# Как при парсинге страницы с помощью php, забрать со страницы переменную js с JSON данными

Tags: javascript, php, json, phpquery

Парсю с помощью курла страницу, и хочу забрать содержимое переменной js в скрипте. Какие есть варианты действия? Подскажите, пожалуйста. Известно, что это глобальная переменная:

`<script>var __SD__ = {"headerMenu":...}</script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это можно сделать с помощью регулярного выражения:

```php
preg_match('/var __SD__ = {"headerMenu":\s?(.*?)}/', $subject, $matches);
```

Значение нужного свойства будет в переменной `$matches[1]`.

**Update.**

```php
preg_match('/<script>var __SD__ = (?<value>{"headerMenu":.*?})<\/script>/', $subject, $matches);
```

В переменной `$matches['value']` будет всё содержимое js-переменной `__SD__`.

Comment: Только часть забирается почему-то...
{"option":{"actionUrl":"\/ajax\/react\/CatalogMenu"

Comment: @IrinaKochenova, насколько у вас большая вложенность этого объекта?

Comment: Ну очень большое дерево. Хотела его разбирать уже потом, после декодирования.

Comment: @IrinaKochenova, отредактировал свой ответ, попробуйте этот вариант.

Comment: Вообще ничего не отдает. (

Comment: preg_match('/<script>var __SD__ = (?<value>.*?)<\/script>/', $html, $matches); Вот так заработало. :)

Comment: Спасибо большое!